# how to create a preferencescreen for each object's instance

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a class Car with these fields:

- color
- model
- name

The user can set the number of cars in preference.

I wish to know the best way to create a dedicated-preference screen for each car where user can edits car's properties.

For now I'm achieving this programmatically: I change dynamically the number of preference screen based on the user choice and for each preferencescreen I use Preference with a different key for each object instance. Example:

Preference Screen for Car 1:
key_car_color_1
key_car_name_1
key_car_model_1

Preference Screen for Car 2:
key_car_color_2
key_car_name_2
key_car_model_2

I'm not sure if it's the best way.

Comment: Give every car an unique id, and append that to shared preference key.

Answer (score 0):

use this library:
https://github.com/orhanobut/hawk

this library can save object:

`Hawk.init(context).build();
Hawk.put("myKey", new Car("red", "123", "BMW"));`

if want to save array of Car:

`List<Car> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.add(new Car("red", "123", "BMW"));
list.add(new Car("blue", "1234", "BMW"));
Hawk.put("cars", list);`
`

get array:

`List<Car> list = Hawk.get(POSTS, new LinkedList<Car>());`

Comment: can you improve your answer showing me how to create a preference screen basing on Hawk key?

Comment: Sorry Reza, but I would to know which is the key to give to a EditTextPreference to edit the car color.

Comment: oh, you talk about SettingActivity? this is not work :(